# Find the exact angle as a function of time for a rod that swings on a frictionless axle

Tags: rotation, moment-of-inertia

This is a simple problem I thought of that I haven't been able to solve.

*Given a rod of uniform mass attached to a fixed axle, find the angle it makes with the horizontal if it is dropped from rest along the horizontal.*

$\theta(t) = ?$

[image: a bad drawing]

I had two approaches, both of them were verified by my professor. The first involves potential energies.

Given that the axles are frictionless, we can say that the energy of the system at any point in time is constant.

$K2 + U2 = K1 + U1$

Because the system starts at rest, K1 is 0.

$K2 + U2 = U1$

The potential energies are entirely due to gravity, and if we focus on the center of gravity of the rod, the lowest point is at $\frac{L}{2}$ below the horizontal, so the potential energy, $U_{g}$ can be expressed as:

$U_{g} = \frac{mgL(1 - \sin(\theta))}{2}$

Hence,

$K2 = U1 - U2 = \frac{mgL(1 - \sin(0))}{2} - \frac{mgL(1 - \sin(\theta))}{2} = mgL\frac{1 - sin(0) - 1 + sin(\theta)}{2} = \frac{mgL\sin(\theta)}{2}$

Now, K2 can be expressed in terms of the angular velocity and rotational inertia of the system:

$\frac{I\omega^{2}}{2} = \frac{mgL\sin(\theta)}{2}$

Since $I = \frac{mL^{2}}{3}$

$\frac{mL^{2}\omega^{2}}{3} = mgL\sin(\theta)$

$\frac{L\omega^{2}}{3} = g\sin(\theta)$

And since the angular velocity, $\omega$ is $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$, or $\theta^{'}$

$\frac{L\theta^{'2}}{3} = g\sin(\theta)$

$\theta^{'2} = \frac{3g\sin(\theta)}{L}$

Taking square roots and seperating variables leads to

$\int \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{\sin(\theta)}} =  \int{\sqrt{\frac{3g}{L}} dt}$

**But the left side can't be integrated. [Wolfram shows this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28dy%2Fdt%29%5E2+%3D+%283g+%2F+l%29+sin%28y%29)**

A simpler approach that was suggested to me uses torques.

Since the sum of the torques is equal to the second derivative of the angle times the moment of inertia, we get

$\sum{\tau} = I\alpha$

The only torque is gravity, which changes based off of the angle the rod is currently at.

$mgL\cos{\theta} = \frac{mL^2}{3} \theta^{''}$

$g\cos{\theta} = \frac{L}{3} \theta^{''}$

$\theta^{''} - \frac{3g}{L}\cos(\theta) = 0$

Which is a second-order, nonlinear O.D.E. of the form

$y'' = f(y)$

**I can't solve it, [but here's something from Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%5E2theta%2Fdt%5E2+%3D+3g+*+cos%28theta%29+%2F+l)**

I looked at [the Pendulum article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum) on Wikipedia, but I'd rather not have my answer involve an infinite series. Is there a closed form solution for this problem?

EDIT:

Maybe a combination of the two final equations could solve it?

$k = \frac{3g}{L}$

$\theta^{'2} = k\sin(\theta)$     **and**     $\theta^{''} = k\cos(\theta)$

Comment: Your system is a rigid rod pendulum, and it's an anharmonic oscillator. In general there is no closed form solution for anharmonic oscillators, and there isn't in this case.

Comment: @doctordoder, Regarding the equation for which you say "But the left side can't be integrated", why does your input to Wolfram have a second derivative? It seems like your input is incorrect.  Maybe you are confusing square of first derivative with second derivative.

Comment: @DavePhD Oops you're right. Fixed.

Comment: equation θ′2=ksin(θ) suffices and is the 'first integral' of equation θ″=kcos(θ). The equation derivations are correct, but mathematically you just can not solve the differential equations to a simple form.

Comment: That's all very unexpected to me. I just can't wrap my head around why such a seemingly simple problem doesn't have a closed form solution.

Comment: @doctordoder Wolfram does give a solution in terms of a Jacob amplitude function if input as (dy/dt)/sqrt(sin(y)) = c.

Comment: @DavePhD I'm in a first semester Physics course, so I don't know what a Jacob amplitude function is. However, I really want to. Do you think you could provide an answer to my question involving an explanation of the Jacob amplitude function solution?

Comment: @doctordoder sorry, I'm not that familiar with Jacobi amplitude function either, I only notice that Wolfram solves in terms of it. Here is a little right up about it: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiAmplitude.html Hopefully someone else here knows more about it than me. Otherwise ask on math stack exchange.